# Idea delivered but not able to find by which means

Tags: dashboard

I was looking for the solution where admin could set default dashboards for the any othere user. As per below idea 
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrcUAAS
This looks like this has been delivered but not able to identify how to do it.
Has anyone encountered or faced this problem. Any pointers would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems there still is no way to assign a certain dashboard to a profile. By default, the user will view the first dashboard on the dashboard list. You can however change the dashboard snapshot that they view by selecting 'Customize Page' next to the dashboard. There you can select which dashboard to view.

The have gone through the comment on the IdeaExchange, but it does not state that this idea has been delivered.

[Reference Link](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000170918)